# Scala do multiple things in the same case branch

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Do you know any good ways to do multiple things in the same case branch?

Something like this

```
case ANODE(NONLEAF, children, depth) =>
{println(" "*(16/depth)+"[]");
children.foreach(nodes_queue.enqueue(_))}
```

This code comes from my design of a function that prints out a tree using a breadth first traverse. The pattern match allows me to get an idea of what kind of node I am printing. So it seems unavoidable for me to do different things in the same case statement (e.g. Print out the node, then enqueue its children for later printing).

The compiler complains about it. I have added curly braces around the statements but that does not help.

The current solution I have for this is to use a function to replace these statements and put a function call after the arrow (=>). But that is ugly and verbose.

I have googled it and only found questions about "pattern match multiple conditions".
Have you got any idea about how to do this in a easy and clean way?

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "the compiler complains about it" - can you provide the exact error? Generally speaking, this should work, even without the curly braces and the semicolon

Comment: The compiler complains about the semicolons. I am quite new to Scala and old habit from other languages caused this error. Thank you for responding! @TzachZohar

Answer (score 4):

you should be able to put them just under the case line :

```
case ANODE(NONLEAF, children, depth) =>
  println(" "*(16/depth)+"[]")
  children.foreach(nodes_queue.enqueue(_))
```

Should be enough.

I usually put braces around to make it clearer though

```
case ANODE(NONLEAF, children, depth) => {
  println(" "*(16/depth)+"[]")
  children.foreach(nodes_queue.enqueue(_))
}
case ...
```

Hope this helps.

PS: I've tested it here https://scastie.scala-lang.org/d0PO3SMxTDuTi6eZM2whyw

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I later realized it was a syntax error-- there should be no semicolons. So basically this is a question from a new learner of Scala :)